# how to access localhost(xampp) from other computer

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I have installed XAMPP on my computer.I want to access my localhost when typing my ip address in another computer.But when i type my ip address it takes me to my modem settings page.Please help me.(I am using the ip address from whatismyip.com)

Comment: Are you behind a router?

Comment: Where does this *another computer* reside? in Internet or in Local network?

Comment: yes, i am using Airtel broadband.

Comment: The other computer resides in Internet.

Comment: Aha. Then you need to forward 80 port of your computer in the modem.

Comment: what is the Name and Model of your modem?

Comment: Well there are a lot of possibilities out there, you should google it first and when you encounter a problem you should post it somewhere on stackexchange, because stackoverflow is more code related than this kind of issues !
btw if you have a dynamic IP and you want to let your friends access your webserver then you should also take a look at www.no-ip.com and if you're behind a router checkout portforward.com ...

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to access your local XAMPP from another computer on your local network, you'll need to use a local ip address.  Likely something like 192.168.x.x.  (on a Windows box, you can type 'ipconfig' into a command prompt to get this IP)

If you're trying to access from outside your local network, you'll need to port-forward port 80 through your router to the computer that is running your XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open port 80 (Or whatever port you are using for Apache) on your firewall. This is pretty well documented here http://portforward.com/ for most routers.

I would also recommend you get something like [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/), makes dynamic IPs less of a hassle.